# Why is the event listener for an unwrapped jQuery element different from the listener on the actual jQuery element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable

See [JSFddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0rda8tav/)

Question: Why will unwrapping the jQuery element and applying an event listener work but when I apply the event listener directly to the jQuery element, it doesn't work?  See below...

With the following code I am trying to capture the drag distance from the original position. When the user drags more than 120 pixels from the origin, I will print to console that we are "outside of the boundary".

If I add the listener by unwrapping the jQuery element, it works as expected and fires the call:

```
$btnItem[0].addEventListener("drag", function (e) { self.handleDrag(e); }, false);
```

If I add the listener to the actual jQuery element, it doesn't fire the call:

```
$btnItem.on('drag', e=> self.handleDrag(e));
```

Any ideas as to why unwrapping the jQuery element works but the actual jQuery method doesn't?  It seems that jQuery loses the connection with the mouse location.

HTML:

```
<div style="padding:100px;">
  <span id="dragMe" draggable="true">Drag</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#dragMe{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;

    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #2e6da4;
}
```

Code:

```
var oPos = [];
function handleDragStart(e) {
  oPos = [e.clientX, e.clientY];
  e.target.style.opacity = '0.4';  // this / e.target is the source node.
}

function handleDrag(e) {
  var nPos = [e.clientX, e.clientY];
  var d = Math.sqrt((oPos[0] - nPos[0]) * (oPos[0] - nPos[0]) + (oPos[1] - nPos[1]) * (oPos[1] - nPos[1]));
  if (d > 120) {
    console.log('outside of the boundary');
  }
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  e.target.style.opacity = '1.0';  // this / e.target is the source node.
}

function jQueryUnWrap(){
  var $btnItem = $("#dragMe");
    $btnItem[0].addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
      handleDragStart(e);
    }, false);
    $btnItem[0].addEventListener("dragend", function (e) {
      handleDragEnd(e);
    }, false);
    $btnItem[0].addEventListener("drag", function (e) {
      handleDrag(e);
    }, false);
}

function jQueryWrap(){
  var $btnItem = $("#dragMe");
  $btnItem.on('dragstart', e=> handleDragStart(e));
  $btnItem.on('dragend', e=> handleDragEnd(e));
  $btnItem.on('drag', e=> handleDrag(e));
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  jQueryUnWrap();
  //jQueryWrap();
});
```

Comment: why are you redefining jQuery? Suggest you create a demo that replicates your problem

Comment: jQuery normalizes the event object, it's likely the normalized event object doesn't contain the properties you are expecting. I suggest logging it to the console and inspecting it. Or, you can go back to the original event object with `e.originalEvent.whateverproperty` however, for cross-browser support, i suggest using the normalized event object if possible. *In this case it doesn't seem to be possible.*

Comment: @charlietfl - it was just a function name, i renamed it.  i added the JSFiddle link above

Comment: @Pointy - self was leftover from me pulling this out of an application, i fixed it

Comment: Well then you don't have to use an arrow function at all - just `$("#dragMe").on("dragstart", handleDragStart)` will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery normalizes the event object to provide an interface that works in all browsers. Unfortunately, this means removing certain properties that aren't supported in all browsers. You can get back to the original event object by accessing the `originalEvent` property.

```
$btnItem.on('dragstart', e=> self.handleDragStart(e.originalEvent));
$btnItem.on('dragend', e=> self.handleDragEnd(e.originalEvent));
$btnItem.on('drag', e=> self.handleDrag(e.originalEvent));
```

Comment: This works in the JSFiddle but in my actual code, e.originalEvent is null.  Any ideas why e.originalEvent would be null?  I'll search for answers in the meantime.

Comment: I have no idea, all same versions of jQuery?

Comment: We're investigating internally.  It might be app-specific due to another plug-in we have.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -3):

JQuery elements are not real elements they are placeholder or wrappers for objects representing the real element. The only way to access the real element outside of Jquery is to use real javascript.

```
el= document.getElementById(iDOfObject);
```

Then you can a listener, however, you should use a function to add a listener as browsers do it different ways

```
function addEvent (el, type, func, rtn) 
{
   if (el == null || el == undefined) return;
   if (el.attachEvent) {
      el.attachEvent("on"+type, func)
   } else if (el.addEventListener) {
      el.addEventListener(type, func, false)
   } else if (document.getElementById) 
   {
      var evFuncs = el["on"+type];
      if (evFuncs != 'undefined' && evFuncs != null) 
      {
         el["on"+type] = function() {
            evFuncs();
            func();
            if (rtn != null)
               return rtn;
         };

         }  else 
      {
            el["on"+type] = func;
         if (rtn != null)
            el["on"+type] += ';return '+ rtn;
      }
      evFuncs = null;
   }
   func = null;
};
```

called like this

```
addEvent(el, "drag", function (e) {
  self.handleDrag(e);
}, false);
```

Comment: The premise of this answer is incorrect: the "real element" is always directly available from a jQuery wrapper, and in fact the code in the OP is taking advantage of that fact.

Comment: No the real element has to be retrieved from jquery likehe did with the call ( var $btnItem = $("#dragMe");) but Jquery is just taking that and applying (el= document.getElementById(iDOfObject);) to find and return the real one to you.   The premise of this answer is that it doesn't work because Jquerys element is not the real element and Javascript will not recognize it unless Jquery calls the (el= document.getElementById(iDOfObject);)because jquery to save memory doesn't store the whole element just their interpretation of it.

Comment: No, jQuery wraps real DOM elements, not fake ones. I don't know where you got that idea but it's incorrect.

Comment: I have written wrappers like Jquery, and I have read the entire jquery script -- I know what it does.

Comment: Type `$("body")[0]` into your developer console and you'll get a reference to the `<body>` DOM element.

Comment: You wanted to know why it doesn't work, I have told you why.  I have used a variety of wrappers including Jquery, and I have written wrappers.  Jquery does not store the real element, if it did your client PC would run out of memory quickly.  Jquery add a wrapper to the element to add their own propeties, rather than prototyping new element properties, that's why some properties are missing.   The wrapper keeps the name space clean so the user can write their own functions without colliding with the query functions.

Comment: Yes, jQuery is a wrapper. It absolutely does store the real elements. Again, try `$("body")[0]` in your browser - you get the real, honest-to-gosh DOM element.

Comment: More directly: `Object.prototype.toString.call($("body")[0])`

Comment: You obviously don't know Javascript...  When you use $("body")[0], Jquery calls the javascript  var body = document.getElementsByTagName( "body" )[ 0 ]; and return those properties of the var body to you.  It does not store them, it just lets you make a simplified call for them.

Comment: Maybe I just don't know what you mean when you say "jQuery does not store them".  When you make a new jQuery object, `$("body")`, that's the point at which jQuery queries the DOM. Inside the jQuery object instance is a reference to the DOM element, which the browser has already built. It doesn't make a *new* DOM element, but it does have a reference to it. The `[0]` suffix is not a function call, it's just ordinary JavaScript code to access the property called "0" on the jQuery object return from `$("body")`.

Comment: No, it doesn't make a new DOM element, it makes a Jquery Object that references to the original DOM element. Jquery makes a call the original object when you make a call to an element reference.  But the reason not all properties are there is because it Jquery didn't add functions to access them.  You can only access properties through Jquery properties that Jquery has chosen to handle.

Comment: If what you're saying is that you can't directly access the DOM element properties as properties of the jQuery object, then we're in agreement :) In the OP, the code uses `$btnItem[0]` to get to the DOM element and call `.addEventListener()`. (That's the part that the OP said was working properly.)

Comment: Yes he didn't understand why the Jquery object didn't handle events. "Any ideas as to why unwrapping the jQuery element works but the actual jQuery method doesn't? I" Which is my point entirely.

Comment: @BaineSumpin i think you missed the point with this question. The question is why does the event object have properties a and b when bound directly using native events, but not when bound with jQuery. I think he understands the difference between native events and jquery events.